# How to copy one xml data into another after last occurrence of a specific element using xslt

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am having two xml files. I want to copy one xml file data into another file under last occurrence of element. Below are the xml I am having :

```
---------- xml-1---------------
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<parent>
....
<form id="1" name="world"/>
 <source id="1" name="abc1"/>
 <source id="2" name="abc2"/>
 <source id="3" name="abc3"/>
 <file id="1" name="xyz"/>
....
</parent> 

----------- xml-2--------------
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<source id="4" data="anything"/>
<source id="5" data="anything"/>
<source id="6" data="anything"/>
<source id="7" data="anything"/>
</root>


------------------The desired output I want-----------------
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<parent>
....
<source id="1" name="abc1"/>
<source id="2" name="abc2"/>
<source id="3" name="abc3"/>
<source id="4" data="anything"/>
<source id="5" data="anything"/>
<source id="6" data="anything"/>
<source id="7" data="anything"/>
<file id="1" name="xyz"
....
</parent> 



============== xslt I am using =============

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="source">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="'id=3'">
          <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="document('file:///D:/Softwares/JEE    eclipse/JEEworkspace/Migration/TestMigrationWithoutDeletingProject/xml2.xml')/*/*"/>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

I am trying to find it out on the basis of id attribute but it is copying xml-2 data after every source element of xml-1 data. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two small problems in your code:

- The call to `<xsl:call-template name="identity"/>` should be outside (or rather before) your `choose` section. By the way: since you not have an `otherwise` section it would be slightly shorter to use `xsl:if` here.
- The test for the correct insertion point should be `test="@id = 3"` since the term `"'id=3'"` is simply a string which always yields `true()`.